# Unity: Can't get animations to work, getting NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I've looked everywhere and tried everything to get my code to work but I still can't get it to work.

I would be very thankful If someone could try to help me fix this issue.

```cs
//PLAYER JUMP MOVEMENT
if (onGround == true && Input.GetKey("w"))
{
    onGround = false;
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, playerJumpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    isJumping = true;
}


if (playerLives <= 0)
{
    Destroy(gameObject, 5f);
}

if (isJumping == true)
{
    anim.SetBool("isJumping", true);
}

if (isJumping == false)
{
    anim.SetBool("isJumping", false);
}
```

The `NullReferenceException` appear at:

> anim.SetBool("isJumping", true);

and

> anim.SetBool("isJumping", false);

Comment: Edit: The errors appear about: "anim.SetBool("isJumping", true);" and "anim.SetBool("isJumping", false);"

Comment: Did you assign `Animator anim` in the inspector or used `anim = GetComponent<Animator>()`? You need to have a reference to this animator.

Comment: Apparently I had first set Animator anim; then in start "Animator anim = GetComponent<Animator>(); When I in start instead only had "anim = GetComponent<Animator>();" as you said, it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class playerController : MonoBehaviour
{
private Animator anim;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Animator anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}
```

The reason this code gave me errors was that I shouldn't have declared anim as an Animator in Start aswell. To simplify this is what the code should look like:

```
public class playerController : MonoBehaviour
{
private Animator anim;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
   anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}
```